# Calculating Percentage Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, tax

Im building a basic income tax calculator but can't figure out how to do all the necessary calculations

```
if income in range(120001, 180000):
    tax = income + 29467
    tax = income / 0.37
```

The given income if in this range needs to be $29,467 plus 37c for each $1 over $120,000 but i have no clue how to apply both calculations correctly

Comment: converting your sentence as it is written into math: `tax = 29467 + 0.37 * (income - 120000)`

Comment: What does this have to do with with percentage calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then try this option.

```py
income = int(input('You income: '))
if income >= 120001 and income <= 180000:
    tax = (29467 + (income - 120001) * 0.37)
    print(f'income = {income} , tax = {tax} dollars')
```

Solution:

```py
You income: 123500
income = 123500 , tax = 30761.63 dollars
```

Answer (score 0):

why did you stated "tax" twice? then the first "tax" state will be wasted which means I shades with the latter "tax".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My translation of the question is this:

If income is in the range 120,000 to 180,000 then add a constant amount of 29,467 then an additional 0.37 for every unit over 120,000.

If that is the case then:

```
def calculate_tax(income):
    return 29_467 + 0.37 * (income - 120_000) if 120_000 < income < 180_000 else 0

print(f'{calculate_tax(150_000):,.2f}')
```

**Output:**

```
40,567.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You have income tax brackets.

0-120000. The rate is 29.467%
120001-180000 the rate is 37%. Based on your data

So for an income of 150000. The income tax is 120000*0.29467 + (150000-120000)*0.37

Comment: Of course you are not accounting for deductions, different rates for married vs single, different types of income